# How to add sticky bit to a directory in exFAT?

Tags: filesystems, chmod, sticky-bit, exfat

I get this error from `Homebrew` when trying to build an application on MacOS 10.10.5, on an exFAT filesystem

```
Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky
```

I use this command to enable sticky-bit, but there does not seem to have any effect

```
$ chmod +t /Volumes/exFAT/tmp
```

Answer (score 5):

exFAT doesn’t support POSIX file attributes, including the sticky bit. There is no way to add it to a directory stored in an exFAT file system.